# Selecting options in a dropdown list via keypress

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

With the current code, when I press the first letter of some option, the control comes to it but it does not work if I press first: two or three or four letters of that option i.e if some option in the list is 'Jquery', then when I press J only,the control comes to it but when I press J and q in succesion or J,q,e in succesion the control vanishes.I want to add this functionality to my dropdown list so please help.

Jquery function:

```
$('#cars').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {

    var $this = $(this);

    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

        $this.find('li').removeClass('active').filter(function() {
            return $(this).text().charAt(0).toLowerCase() === key;
        }).first().addClass('active');

    });

    $('#').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
        $(document).unbind("keypress");
    });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown" id="cars">
<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle">Models<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
<li><a class="hc" href="#">Volvo</a></li>
<li><a class="hc" href="#">Saab</a></li>
<li><a class="hc" href="#">Mercedes</a></li>
<li><a class="hc" href="#">Polo</a></li>
<li><a class="hc" href="#">Vento</a></li>
<li><a class="hc" href="#">Zen</a></li>
<li><a class="hc" href="#">Nano</a></li>
<li><a class="hc" href="#">Fortuner</a></li>
<li><a class="hc" href="http://www.audi.com/">Audi</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like

```js
var $this = $('#cars');

var timer, chars = '';
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

  if (timer) {
    chars += key;
  } else {
    chars = key;
  }
  console.log('searc', chars)

  var regex = new RegExp('^' + chars, 'i');

  $this.find('li').removeClass('active').filter(function() {
    return regex.test($(this).text());
  }).first().addClass('active');

  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    chars = '';
    timer = undefined;
  }, 500)

});
```

```css
.active a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group dropdown" id="cars">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle">Models<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
    <li><a class="hc" href="#">Volvo</a></li>
    <li><a class="hc" href="#">Saab</a></li>
    <li><a class="hc" href="#">Mercedes</a></li>
    <li><a class="hc" href="#">Polo</a></li>
    <li><a class="hc" href="#">Vento</a></li>
    <li><a class="hc" href="#">Zen</a></li>
    <li><a class="hc" href="#">Nano</a></li>
    <li><a class="hc" href="#">Fortuner</a></li>
    <li><a class="hc" href="http://www.audi.com/">Audi</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the loop and setting the active class to all elements that match, filter and then select the first element in the collection only

```
$('#cars').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {

    var $this = $(this);

    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

        $this.find('li').removeClass('active').filter(function() {
            return $(this).text().charAt(0).toLowerCase() === key;
        }).first().addClass('active');

    });

    $('#').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
        $(document).unbind("keypress");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    $('#cars').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('li').removeClass('active');
        $this.find('li').removeClass('active').filter(function() {
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(key) ==0;
        }).first().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: @ Rohan Kumar:No dude, it does not work.The control just stops on the first option of the list..